# Different classes of Linux packages

Tags: package-management, packaging, pkgbuild

I do know that there are 4 different classes of packages in Linux:

1. Packages provided by the operating system
2. Packages provided by third parties
3. Self-made packages of third-party software
4. Self-made packages of your own software

I am trying to find examples for each of these classes so I can better understand it. So I came up with the following:

1. packges like firewalld or kernel packages
2. packages like virtual box or vmware player
3. Am no sure about this one, maybe a developer developing a package that's related to or built on another 3rd party software?? Tmux custom versions ?? maybe
4. this one is just easy

Am I right in these examples, I would need just a little bit more elaboration here on #3. Self-made packages of third-party software, do you guys have any examples. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Linux kernel sources include infrastructure to directly build a Debian or RPM package for the kernel, kernel modules, and kernel headers, but the upstream developers at kernel.org do not distribute these packages themselves.  There are a small number of other projects (usually small ones) that take a similar approach.  I'd say that probably qualifies as the only example of item 3 that most people would recognize (and it's almost certainly the most common, though most people who build their own kernels from upstream sources usually just skip dealing with the package manager and install the kernel and modules directly).

Slightly OT, but I feel it's worth commenting that most package managers do not distinguish things directly in this manner, they only care what repository a package came from, or if it was manually installed as a local package, and they don't care whether something you install by hand directly is built locally or not (and thus cases 2, 3 and 4 above are handled identically by pretty much every package manager in existence).